# Android edittext and different gravity

Tags: android, android-edittext, gravity

I am using an edittext like below. I'd like text on it to be written from top-left, let's say like a normal sms message text. If I use gravity="top" or gravity = "left" or gravity = "top|left" the results are exactly the same (cursor is put in same spot). But is there an actual difference between them all? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's a hint, not the text.  It displays only when empty, and as soon as you hit any character it disappears.  So the text IS entering upper left.  Or you can set the hint to not appear and get rid of it.

Comment: Testing some writting on it gave same results too :/

Comment: Do a setHint("") on the edit view, since you obviously don't want a hint.

Comment: No, hint is fine :D I just say, i see no difference between how text is put on the edittext

Comment: So maybe I'm not understanding what you want.  I thought you were confused by the hint coming after the cursor.  Apparently that isn't it.  The cursor is at the top left.  You want text added top left.  What isn't working right?

Comment: sorry, maybe it is my bad english. sorry for confusing you. everything is working fine. and it is working the exact way whether I set gravity to the top, left or top-left. So, I ask, is there any difference that I may not see yet?

Comment: Not for top or left.  Try right or bottom.  Top and left are the defaults.

Answer (score 0):

if your parent layout define gravity=right than if you use gravity=top then latter writing start from top right most corner so your child view you must specify top|left to start like screen